# Can't get this GROUP BY or DISTINCT right

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query, group-by, distinct

On `MySQL 5.7.34` I have this simple db structure. Important columns are `domain name`, `domain total links in`, but entries are duplicate (once for each found link from various sources), I need to **select domain only once** (`link_to_domain`) and sort it by `link_to_domain_total_links_in` DESC; Not sure how to render it here, here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domain_to_domain_links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link_to_domain_hash` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `link_to_domain_total_links_in` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `link_to_domain` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `link_from_domain` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=270245 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `domain_to_domain_links` (`id`, `link_to_domain_hash`, `link_to_domain_total_links_in`, `link_to_domain`, `link_from_domain`) VALUES
(1, 'c9b13094745bae79', 3, 'example.com', 'from-other-site1.com'),
(1, 'c9b13094745bae79', 3, 'example.com', 'from-other-site2.com'),
(1, 'c9b13094745bae79', 3, 'example.com', 'from-other-site3.com'),
(2, 'c43f16c897f72994', 2, 'foo.com', 'from-other-site4.com'),
(3, 'c43f16c897f72994', 2, 'foo.com', 'from-other-site5.com');
```

This returns exactly what I need but from what I understand it actually counts the entries (as links) at query time, I need it to get it from the `link_to_domain_total_links_in` so that it runs faster:

```
SELECT link_to_domain, COUNT(*) AS my_links_counter 
FROM domain_to_domain_links 
GROUP BY link_to_domain 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Also `link_to_domain_hash` is indexed, if it can take advantage of that when selecting it should be faster than `link_to_domain`, but this is not critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your table correctly, `link_to_domain_total_links_in` represents the number of rows that exist in the table for that particular `link_to_domain`.

Instead of `COUNT()` you can use the `MAX()` or `MIN()` aggregate function on the `link_to_domain_total_links_in` column (since it'll always be the same for any instance of `link_to_domain`).

But at that rate you can just add `link_to_domain_total_links_in` to the `GROUP BY` clause, and then you're allowed to `SELECT` and / or `ORDER BY` it.

But then you're not aggregating anything anymore and don't even need a `GROUP BY` clause, rather you can just use the `DISTINCT` keyword against your two columns like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    link_to_domain,
    link_to_domain_total_links_in AS my_links_counter 
FROM domain_to_domain_links 
ORDER BY link_to_domain_total_links_in DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well, I tried something similar but not sure what I was doing wrong. Looks simple now :)